# Unresolved class '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

After i updated Android Studio i get this error in my xml for my viewpager.
 Weird thing is it works fine and the project builds without any problems.

What is the reason that **'@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'** is an 
 **Unresolved class**?

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewPager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"           
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My viewpager is inside a **CoordinatorLayout**.

Comment: Try "File -> Invalidate caches / restart..." and the select "Invalidate and restart"

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana Just tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Still showing 'unresolved class'

Comment: And assume you've already tried to do a "Build -> Clean" (if not, just try it). Else, take a look at this https://github.com/rock3r/deep-clean (WARNING: this is heavy stuff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here. Looks like bug in IDE, not in app.

New project (default Tabs) in Android Studio 3.4 shows a warning:

> Unresolved class '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'
>   Inspection info: Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

Not resolved by invalidating cache, clean build, project sync.

Code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
/>
```

When i removed the last line the tabs were not working correctly:

- fragment in second tab was not shown
- scroll top position is wrong, goed under top bar

So the IDE cant find it, but the app is definitely using the string/class.

Answer (score 10):

Those who use or migrated to AndroidX, you can use the following fix to remove the error. This also works in Android Studio 3.4

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Answer (score 2):

As Barry Staes pointed out, it looks like a bug in the IDE. However, if you're using the design library, this syntax should make the error go away:

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Comment: It works in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem multiple times.

I always use `tools:layout_behavior` instead of `app:layout_behavior`

Comment: yes error gone. but layout not behaving like the code of app:layout_behavior. I once again select app:layout_behavior

Answer (score 1):

Go to app level  **build.gradle** and add :

```
def support_version="28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
```

if not working, modify only the `support_version`